# node.js reading ts file as js in the npm root directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, directory, command-line-interface, require

I've got a Nodejs CLI written with typescript.  It is dynamically reading an external file `init.ts`.

```
       const {init} = require(initFunctionFile)
```

The goal is that other packages can run the CLI using their own `init.ts` file.  If `init.ts` is in a plain directory, it works fine.  But if it's in the global npm root directory, or if a package containing init.ts is not stored locally and is executed using `npx`, I'm getting the error:

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/package-name/.../init.ts:5
    init: async function(command: string, codeDir: string){
                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

It seems that node thinks the file is js.  What is happening here, and what's a better way to do this?

Comment: have you tried ts-node?

Comment: Thanks @ABOS!  Yes, I'm using ts-node, which lets the cli itself run with node.  The problem is that I can't read the file itself.  As a workaround, I'm currently copying the package folder containing the init.ts file to a directory outside of the global root npm directory just to read that file.